# Passing a mysql connection to expression routing middleware function as argument

Tags: node.js, express, database-connection, middleware

I am wondering if I can pass a connected database instance to an express middleware as an argument.
For example:

```
// in app.js
const mysql = require('mysql');
const mysqlCon = mysql.createConnection({
  // some configurations...
})
mysqlCon.connect((err)=> if(err) throw err);
```

then in a separate file...

```
// in a separate file called: login handler
const loginHandler = (req, res, dbCon) => {
  // query database and stuff...
} 
module.exports = loginHanlder;
```

then back in app.js passes the established mysql connection into the middleware handler

```
// back in app.js
// a route
const loginHandler = require('./handlers/loginHanlder.js');
app.get('/login', loginHanlder(req, res, mysqlCon));
```

Will this work? Or are there a conventionally better way of achieving this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're trying to do it won't work, as `req,res` will be undefined.

However, you could create a factory function that takes the connection as a parameter and retours a route-handler function. Since the function that will be returned is a closure, it will have access to the db-connection in the parent scope. Something like:

```
function getRequestHandler(dbConn) {
        return function (req, res, next) {
            // use dbConn here to do stuff
        }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
const dbConn = initConnection(); // connect to your db here and return the connection instance
app.get('/login', getRequestHandler(dbConn));
```

Alternatively, if you don't want/need to create your own factory function, you can simply do:

```
app.get('/login', (req, res) => loginHandler(req, res, mysqlCon));
```

Comment: I need to research what factory functions are; anyway, will the following code work, if I provide the request and response object like this?
`app.get('/login', (req, res)=> loginHanlder(req, res, mysqlCon));`

Comment: It's just a fancy name for a function that returns another function :) Yes, this way it should work. It's basically the same thing I did.